# SSL socket Server tool for windows

Tags: windows, server, ssl

I'm looking for a windows software that I can use as **Socket Server** for testing my Client with these options:

- Support SSL and TLS with certificate management
- Simple User interface with I/O area where I put messages to send and view received messages

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean a websocket server, I would recommend using Node-Red. This is a Node.JS based visual flow-based tool originally designed for IoT work. It fully supports websockets. As well as the standard version, there are even versions that will run just in a browser or run on the desktop using Electron.

- [Node-Red Home page](http://nodered.org/)
- [PageNodes](https://iceddev.com/blog/introducing-pagenodes/) - completely in-browser version of Node-Red, no server needed
- [electron-node-red](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-node-red) - wrap Node-Red with Electron to run natively

Using Node-Red, you can easily set up nodes to send and receive over websockets.

HTTPS is relatively straight-forwards, follow the instructions on the Node-Red documentation site.